# JavaScript button. - Add/Remove class/id styles onClick. - Display: none/block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am trying to make it so when you click the button:

- the button and Heading are removed;
- the hidden content is displayed.

Then the hidden content has a back button. Once you click that it reverts all changes.

The JavaScript code below doesn't work, but it should give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I am not sure how to contact both ids/classes since I need to do both.

```
<script>
$('.mobileAdultBtn').on('click' function () {
    $('#vContentLeft').css('display', 'block');
    $('.backBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobileAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.productHeading ').css('display', 'none');
});

$('.backBtn').on('click' function () {
    $('#vContentLeft').css('display', 'none');
    $('.backBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobileAdultBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.productHeading ').css('display', 'block');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but your selectors are unnecessarily verbose.  change `$(this).find('.backBtn')` to `$('.backBtn')` .   What isn't working for you? Could you provide a fiddle with html as well?  the code looks fine standing by itself, though there is no need to separate this into 2 `<script>` tags

Comment: `The javascript code i made doesnt work I know` wrong. The code is completely valid if put in the right place and "works". You should explain what *does not work*, why, and eventually share some sample HTML and CSS. You're manipulating elements using JS remember? I can see none.

Comment: I mean i didnt expect it to work. I just threw it together from an example that I saw. But cant find anything that will work. When i click the button it doesnt change any of the styles. Its all hooked up properly to each class/ID so are u saying the code should work as is? You dont see any mistakes?

Im gonna update my example to your suggestions.

Comment: found syntax error: you are missing a comma in between your arguments `.on('click' function () {...` should be `.on('click', function () {...`

Comment: Eric post that as solution please. You win kind sir!

Comment: done, glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a syntax you are missing a comma in between your arguments

```
.on('click' function () {...
```

should be

```
.on('click', function () {...
```

Comment: Yes Thank you sooo much! Works great now.

Comment: Eric could you tell me how to put mutliple styles into the code?

So instead of $('#vContentRight').css('display', 'block');
I need: $('#vContentRight').css('display', 'block'),('background', 'blue');

Comment: sure, 2 options.  **1)**  you can chain them   `.css('display','block').css('background','blue');`  or **2)**   pass in an object `.css({display:'block',background:'blue'});`

Comment: NOTE: if you pass in an object, and your css attribute has a `-` in it (ex `margin-left` ) then you must either put quotes `.css({'margin-left':'1px','margin-right':'1px'});` around it or use camelCase   `.css({marginLeft:'1px',marginRight:'1px'});`

Comment: I would recommend toggling a class name on the elements, then add all the styles in the css. @Portal_Zii, if this answered your question, then please click the checkmark to mark it as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

You click function is missing a comma after "click", it should be:

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function(){
```

But .on is a general event handler and more than is necessary for your purposes, use the simpler function .click():

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
     `//hide and show things 
}`
```

**Issue 2**

Using `$(this).find('#whateverid')` looks only at objects with that id  that are children of the object that the function was called on, the button. So unless the header is inside the button that will not work.

You want to check for wherever that id will appear on the page:

```
$('#whateverid')
```

Comment: I removed the $(this).find and updated the description. But it still doesnt work. When i click the button. It doesnt even make itself disapear let alone change styles of other elements. The code is at the bottom of the page with the rest of my working scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

HTML

```
<button class="toggle ">Show</button>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>World</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
   background:silver;
}
.content.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
(function($){
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.content').toggleClass('hidden');

  })
}(jQuery));
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVbjNN

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('.mobileAdultBtn').click(function(){
    $('#vContentLeft').css('display', 'block');
    $('.backBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobileAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.productHeading ').css('display', 'none');
});

$('.backBtn').click(function(){
    $('#vContentLeft').css('display', 'none');
    $('.backBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobileAdultBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.productHeading ').css('display', 'block');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves your doubts. It is always recommended to use native JavaScript code whenever possible. And do not use jQuery as basic operations. Assist the performance of your program.

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function boton1(){
        document.getElementById("backBtn").setAttribute("style","display: block");
        document.getElementById("vContentLeft").setAttribute("style","display: block");
             document.getElementById("mobileAdultBtn").setAttribute("style","display:none");
         
        
        
      }
      function boton2(){
        document.getElementById("backBtn").setAttribute("style","display: none");
        document.getElementById("vContentLeft").setAttribute("style","display: none");
             document.getElementById("mobileAdultBtn").setAttribute("style","display:block");
        
      }
</script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="accion" id="mobileAdultBtn" onclick="boton1();">
    
    <input type="button" value="back" id="backBtn" onclick="boton2();">
    <div id="vContentLeft">Texto con contenido, developer @locoalien Fallow http://www.twitter.com/locoalien</div>
    
    </body>
  
  </html>
```

Below are pictures of the execution is observed.
[image: Function Number One DOM JavaScript]

[image: Function Number Two DOM JavaScript]

[image: Button Functions]

I hope it helps you. Do not forget to follow me on twitter @locoalien